# Change SEO Link in the footer

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14

Does anybody here know how to change SEO link In the footer?

I installed a extension for Sitemap and I want to link it to

```
www.mywebsite.com/sitemap
```

instead of the default link

```
www.mywebsite.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category
```

Comment: which magento version?

Comment: i'm using magento enterprise 1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento  managed this sitemap from catalog helper.you need to change there

copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Map.php`
 to  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Map.php`

then goto **local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Map.php** and  here you find that function `getCategoryUrl`

```
return $this->_getUrl('catalog/seo_sitemap/category');
```

change

```
 return $this->_getUrl('sitemap');
```

Comment: can you give me the path?

Comment: hey Alyssa is it works?

Comment: Heeey! It works! You're a genius!

Comment: I've tried this and the link in the footer changes, however, I am getting a 404 page when I click the updated link.  Edit: Magento CE 1.9.1